# Return newest row added in MySQL

Tags: php, database, primary-key, mysql

I was wondering what the code would look like to go into a table and then get the primary key in the last row  that was added to the table.

How would you go across doing that I do not have a timestamp in the table for the rows in the database if that helps.

Comment: got an auto_increment there?

Comment: if not just add a timestamp?

Comment: @Dominik yes i do have a auto_increment

Comment: then order by this. auto_increment will have the highest number for the most recent input... To for an answer here you should probably supply some code or at least the table layout

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Purely MySQL solution:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

---

For PHP with [pdo](/questions/tagged/pdo) method

```
$lastId = $con->lastInsertId();
```

Comment: to my understanding that would only work if the script has actually inserted something and not when you just want to find out what the last insert was but I haven't checked that and am not sure thats what maxgee wants anyway ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
    $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
    if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db('mydb');
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable (product) values ('kossu')");
    printf("Last inserted record has id %d\n", mysql_insert_id());
```